# Wear TileService Layout Component accessibility

Tags: accessibility, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, tile-service, wear-tile

Any way can i add accessibility to `TileService` layout component like `LayoutElementBuilders.Text`. I can't see any api to set accessibility. Anyone have idea or solution, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the semantics modifier

```
Text.Builder()
                    .setText("AAA")
                    .setModifiers(
                        Modifiers.Builder()
                            .setSemantics(
                                Semantics.Builder()
                                    .setContentDescription(
                                        "Hello World Text Element"
                                    ).build()
                            ).build()
                    )
```

Comment: Great. Worked. Thanks